# Adding fragments to a Constraint Layout programmatically

Tags: android, user-interface, kotlin

I'm trying to add two fragments to a Constraint Layout and then set their constraints, to ensure the lower fragment is always snapped to the bottom of the application's layout and the upper fragment can fill any remaining space. My code for doing this looks like the following:

```
        val fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
        fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.app_con_layout,fragmentA)
        fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.app_con_layout,fragmentB)
        fragmentTransaction.commit()

        val mConstraintLayout = findViewById<ConstraintLayout>(R.id.app_con_layout)
        val set = ConstraintSet()

        set.clone(mConstraintLayout)
        set.connect(fragmentA.id, ConstraintSet.TOP, R.id.app_toolbar, ConstraintSet.BOTTOM)
        set.connect(fragmentB.id, ConstraintSet.BOTTOM, mConstraintLayout.id, ConstraintSet.BOTTOM)
        set.applyTo(mConstraintLayout)
```

This doesn't work and the two fragments seem to end up on top of each other. My understanding is that fragment's won't get unique IDs, and instead I should use tags as part of the fragment transaction to be able to uniquely refer to fragments later on. But that doesn't seem compatible with ConstraintSet's `connect` method, which requires an integer id.

What's the correct way to solve this? I could add frame layouts to the constraint layout in xml and then add the fragments to those, but that feels like a workaround so I suspect I'm missing something.

Comment: You are adding the two fragments to the same container, what did you expect to be the end result?

Comment: @abstractArrow Apologies if I've not understood you, but it's perfectly valid to add multiple fragments in to a layout component as far as I'm aware - I've done this with Linear Layouts in the past with no problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the wrong ID for `set.connect(…)`. Fragment has View and you'll need that View ID if you want to pass it into `connect(…)`. That's too complex for me because then you will need to wait until Fragment lifecycle has started (`fragmentTransaction.commit()` is asynchronous). I don't know if `commitNow()` can help you for this.

> I could add frame layouts to the constraint layout in xml

I would take this approach if I were you. That way the layout stays in XML and only adding the fragments to their placeholder (and dealing with their lifecycles and events propagation) will be done programmatically.